# How to Change default Doctype to DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: aptana

Just installed Aptana Studio 3. For the life of me I can't figure out how to simply tell Aptana...

"I want to create a web project that uses XHTML 1.0 Transitional as my default doc type."

Can anyone show me how to change the default doctype used in newly created web projects? I can't find this anywhere. Every web IDE I've ever used makes this a very easy selection. When I try and look through the documentation I'm always redirected from Aptana Studio to Titanium documentation and no mention of default doctypes in those docs either.

If you can point me to a link that explains how to accomplish this, I would be greatfull. This IDE is perfect for our needs.

Should I switch to Titanium Desktop? Is this the new and improved Aptana or something? The documentation redirect from Aptana docs to Titanium peaked my curiosity.

Thanks for your time.
JBanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't choose a default doctype--you just choose a template that embodies that. So, create a new web project, and then do File > New From Template > HTML, and choose "XHTML 1.0 Transitional" as the file.

Comment: Ahhh.. Thank you very much Ingo. Much appreciated. Worked like a charm.

Comment: For someone not using a software for creating webpages such as Aptana Studio what exactly would that markup look like?